# 4 float color to one float in java, and back again in openGL ES 2.0 shader

Tags: java, opengl-es-2.0, bit-manipulation, shader

I am trying to send one color with every vertex that goes in to the shader, but in only one float value. I think is weird that you cannot send 4 bytes as attributes with every vertex, but sense it's not possible I am going to try to pack RGBA in a single float variable, so this is my code:

Jave code (that packs the values in one float):

```
private float fourfColor2One(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    long temp = (byte) (r * 255);
    float res = temp << 24;

    temp = (byte) (g * 255);
    res += temp << 16;

    temp = (byte) (b * 255);
    res += temp << 8;

    temp = (byte) (a * 255);
    res += temp;

    return res;
}
```

Shadercode (that packs it up):
Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute float fColor;
uniform vec2 vCamPos;
uniform float fZoom;
uniform mat4 m_projectionMat;
varying float v_Color;
void main() {
  vec4 position = vec4(vPosition.x - vCamPos.x - 16., vPosition.y - vCamPos.y - ((32. / "+ GraphicsRenderer.mScnR +") / 2.), -1., 1.);
  position = position * m_projectionMat;
  gl_Position = vec4(position.xy * fZoom, -1, 1);
  v_Color = fColor;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying float v_Color;
void main() {
   uint temp = uint(v_Color);
   float r = temp & 0xf000;
   float g = temp & 0x0f00;
   float b = temp & 0x00f0;
   float a = temp & 0x000f;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, a);
}
```

So I have three questions:

1. Is this concept even possible?
2. The conversions is not correct, right? I assume that when I convert from and to float, the conversion does not retain the order of the bit, but rather the values it represent in that datatype, right?
3. Right now the shader gives me -1 back when i run:
   glGetAttribLocation(mShaderHandle, "fColor");
   But this one works one line before:
   glGetAttribLocation(mShaderHandle, "vPosition");

So, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A float can only hold 24 bits accurately. If you want to store 32-bits of information you will need to use an `int`, `long` or `double`

Comment: Holy crap! How have I messed that... thanks!

Comment: But wait... here it says that OpenGL ED 2.0 has 32 bit floats: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf

Bit I use ES 2.0 thought the libGDX wrapper in java... hmm, this just got very complicated...

Comment: 32-bit floats have a sign (1-bit) and exponent (8 bits) and 23-bit mantissa (which has 24-bit of accuracy)

Comment: Even if you only wanted 24-bits you could treat it as a `uint`, it would have to be a `float`

Comment: So there is no way to transfer a int to a float with the it order intact in java?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16928/discussion-between-mockarutan-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 2):

I would convert

```
private static int fourfColor2One(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
    return (Math.round(r * 255) << 24) + 
           (Math.round(g * 255) << 16) +
           (Math.round(b * 255) << 8) +
           Math.round(a * 255);
}
```

This assumes your scale is 0.0 to 1.0 in your "shader" you assume the scale is 0.0 to 255.0

---

Some "pseudo code" to reverse this

```
float r = (temp & 0xf000)/255.0;
float g = (temp & 0x0f00)/255.0;
float b = (temp & 0x00f0)/255.0;
float a = (temp & 0x000f)/255.0;
```

Comment: Oh, right, the shader language works with 0.0 to 1.0... forgot that. But thanks! Now, can I convert that int to a float with the exact same bit order?

Comment: To turn a scale of [0.0, 255.0] in [0.0, 1.0] you divide by 255.0

Comment: Yeas i know that... but not getting a int into a float buffer with the same bit order...

Comment: The byte endianess should be the same for the whole CPU. It is possible, but unlikely that your GPU has a different endianess to your CPU, but I have never seen this.