# Opengl - GLSL - Storing 4 bytes inside one float and sending it to a shader

Tags: java, android, performance, shader, opengl-es-2.0

using: opengl es 2.0 on an android device

I want to draw a lot of points. Right now I need 3 floats to store each pixels position and then 4 more floats to store its color (rgba). 
Instead I want to store the color inside 1 float (4 bytes). So overall I would only need 4 floats per pixel instead of 7.

In java i cast the color like this:

```
public float getOneFloatColor(float fr, float fg, float fb, float fa) {
    char r = (char)(fr*255);
    char g = (char)(fg*255);
    char b = (char)(fb*255);
    char a = (char)(fa*255);
    return (r << 24) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a;
}
```

**Update:** This function might be flawed, it might only save rgb but not a. I think it has something to do with the cast from int to float in the end at the return statement.

I then put it inside a large float array: `float vertices[]`
First I put the position (xyz) and then the color

After that i draw it like this:

```
ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);
vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

vertexBuffer.position(0);
vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
vertexBuffer.position(0);

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PixelShader.sPosition);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PixelShader.sColor);

int stride = 16; // 4 floats each 4 byte

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PixelShader.sPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, vertexBuffer);
vertexBuffer.position(3); // move offset of buffer by 3 (after xyz)
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PixelShader.sColor, 4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, stride, vertexBuffer);

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexBufferSize);
```

My vertex shader:

```
precision   mediump     float;
attribute   vec4        a_Position;
attribute   vec4        a_Color;
varying     vec4        v_Color;

void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
    v_Color = a_Color;
    gl_Position = a_Position;
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
precision   mediump     float;
varying     vec4        v_Color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_Color.r/255., v_Color.g/255., v_Color.b/255., v_Color.a/255.);
}
```

This does not work, the position of the pixels will be correct, but the color is missing. If i dont divide the color by 255 in the fragment shader, then sometimes i get some sort of color, but never the right one.

I think my problem lies at this line:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PixelShader.sColor, 4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, stride, vertexBuffer);
```

I want that opengl transforms my 1 float into 4 unsigned bytes, but that is not what is happening? What am I doing wrong? Is there another solution for this problem? Is this even possible?

I found a similar question with a different approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515909/4-float-color-to-one-float-in-java-and-back-again-in-opengl-es-2-0-shader)
But it has no solution.

---

## Update:

I tried a different approach -> Sending 1 float containing rgb data to the shaders and converting it inside the vertexShader.

In Java:

```
// takes in 3 floats in the range of 0 - 1 and transforms them to one
public float rgbToFloat2(float r, float g, float b, float factor) {
    r = (int)(r*factor); g = (int)(g*factor); b = (int)(b*factor);
    return r/factor + g/Math.pow(factor,2) + b/Math.pow(factor,3);
}
```

Then i changed the glVertexAttribPointer line to send 1 rgb float:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PixelShader.sColor, 1, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, vertexBuffer);
```

Changed the vertex shader:

```
precision   highp     float;
attribute   vec4        a_Position;
attribute   float        a_Color;
varying     vec4        v_Color;

vec3 floatToRGB(float f, float factor) {
    vec3 rgb;
    rgb.r = f*factor;
    rgb.g = fract(rgb.r)*factor;
    rgb.b = fract(rgb.g)*factor;

    rgb.r = floor(rgb.r)/factor;
    rgb.g = floor(rgb.g)/factor;
    rgb.b = floor(rgb.b)/factor;
    return rgb;
}

void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
    v_Color = vec4(floatToRGB(a_Color, 255.), 1.0);
    gl_Position = a_Position;
}
```

and fragment shader:

```
precision   highp     float;
varying     vec4        v_Color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

I tested this conversion method in java and it worked very well, but as soon as i try to convert it inside the shader it doesnt work anymore. I also tried different factors, even a very low factor like 10 doesn't work. I have no idea why not, it is like magic! I will give up now but leave this here.

Comment: `varying` variables are interpolated along according to the position of the fragment on the primitive when passed from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.

Comment: but since there is only one vertex per point, it shouldn't change right? i thought about using uniforms but i dont want to call glUniform4f for each pixel. Is there another way?

Comment: Why don't you do the conversion in the vertex shader and pass a `vec4` to the fragment shader. Or try to use the [`flat`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers) qualifier.

Comment: Thx for the tips. Sadly GLSL ES doesnt support the flat qualifier. I will try to do the conversion in the vertex shader. But I am not sure how opengl handles floats, I think there is a difference between the cpu floats and the gpu floats. Also I am afraid that this might be different between devices, but I dont know. I will try.

Comment: You may want to use `precision highp float;` to keep values intact.

Also, please try this solution for packing/unpacking RGBA values: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/68700/49555